# radio buttons not initializing correctly when entering a new page

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope

I have a simple form that gets it's initial values from an object that I pass into the form's controller. Other models are displaying the correct values, but the correct radio button is not being checked.
Here is the object that contains the initial values:

```
$scope.proposal[b_size]: 13
$scope.proposal[proposal_key]: 690dae2350cf41feaadc5d8e63fc2b55
...
```

and here is the template fragment:

```
 <input type="radio" ng-model="proposal.b_size" value="7" />7 by 7&nbsp;&nbsp;
 <input type="radio" ng-model="proposal.b_size" value="13" />13 by 13&nbsp;&nbsp;
 <input type="radio" ng-model="proposal.b_size" value="19" />19 by 19&nbsp;&nbsp;
```

I have tried both setting the b_size to {} in the controller before setting it to the correct value, and just setting it to the correct value. In both cases, none of the radio buttons are set.

Comment: `{{proposal.b_size}}` after `7&nbsp;&nbsp;` and check what value is coming.. or try to parse the value to integer and then assign to model.

Comment: can you create a jsfiddle with your issue? You can fork this one to get started: https://jsfiddle.net/tjaart/30y1m0d6/2/

Answer (score 1):

Currently what happening is, because of `value` attribute `7` is considered as `'7'`(string 7), and when you assign value to `ng-model`, it checks radio box value, so comparison of `'7'` and 7 get `false` and nothing got pre-selected.

Change `value` attribute to `ng-value` will help you to preserve type of value.

```
<input type="radio" ng-model="proposal.b_size" ng-value="7" />7 by 7&nbsp;&nbsp;
<input type="radio" ng-model="proposal.b_size" ng-value="13" />13 by 13&nbsp;&nbsp;
<input type="radio" ng-model="proposal.b_size" ng-value="19" />19 by 19&nbsp;&nbsp;
```

[**Demo Plunker**](https://plnkr.co/edit/QgFBhvBe9KIyneRGy2uQ?p=preview)

Comment: @garey does this helped you?

Answer (score 0):

Can you make sure properties in controller are single quoted; like:
`$scope.proposal['b_size']: 13`